# Plotting a line graph by using data from an array of structs (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

A text file contains 100 Students, with each line consisting of: first name, last name, exam 1, exam 2, exam 3. I read the data from the text file into an array of structs. But now I need to crate a line graph with the number of students on the x-axis and each of their three exam scores on the y axis. With exam 1 in Green, Exam 2 in Red and exam 3 in blue. And with horizontal lines that indicate the average for each exam. theoretically it should look like this.

[image]

This is the code I have come up with so far but I haven't been able to figure out even where to begin with creating the line graph.

```
#include "library.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct StudentInfo {
string first;
string last;
int e1;
int e2;
int e3;
};

void main()
{
 
ifstream in_file;

in_file.open("exams.txt");
StudentInfo students[100];
int count = 0;

while(in_file >> students[count].first){
    in_file >> students[count].last;
    in_file >> students[count].e1;
    in_file >> students [count].e2;
    in_file >> students [count].e3;
    count ++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
 
    cout << students[i].first << " " << students[i].last << " " << students[i].e1 << " " << students[i].e2 << " " << students[i].e3 << endl;
}

in_file.close();
}
```

Comment: DO you have a graphics library you are supposed to use for this assignment? C++ doesn't know what a pixel is without help, so you'll have to figure out which graphics library you're going to use before you go much further.

Comment: Common in use GUI libraries comprise [Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-canvas-example.html), [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) or [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/), but there are *many* others you might want to peek in. Try `c++ GUI framework` with your favourite search engine...

Comment: It's surprising that you've been asked to complete a graphics assignment without the first idea about how to do graphics. I would check that you've understood the requirements correctly. However there are things you can do without graphics. You could calculate the averages for instance. Being able to do that will be needed in any case once you get the graphics part sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely want to use a Graphics Library.
There are some out there that will draw graphs for you.
There are others out there that can only draw shapes.

I created this ugly example using SFML since it is what I am most familiar with:
[image: SFML graph]

I hard coded a lot for the sake of speed.

This works by drawing the border:

```cpp
        std::array<sf::Vertex, 3> border {
            sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0.f, 0.f), sf::Color::Black),
            sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0.f, 100.f), sf::Color::Black),
            sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(full_width, 100.f), sf::Color::Black)
        };
        window.draw(border.data(), border.size(), sf::PrimitiveType::LineStrip);
```

Creating vectors of vertices to store the line part of the line chart:

```cpp
        std::vector<sf::Vertex> line_graph_1;
        std::vector<sf::Vertex> line_graph_2;
        std::vector<sf::Vertex> line_graph_3;
```

Iterating through each student and adding vertices to these vectors:

```cpp
            line_graph_1.emplace_back(sf::Vector2f(x, 100.f - student.e1), sf::Color::Red);
            line_graph_2.emplace_back(sf::Vector2f(x, 100.f - student.e2), sf::Color::Green);
            line_graph_3.emplace_back(sf::Vector2f(x, 100.f - student.e3), sf::Color::Blue);
```

Drawing the names at the bottom:

```cpp
            text.setString(student.first + ' ' + student.last);
            const auto bounds = text.getLocalBounds();
            text.setPosition(
                x + bounds.left - bounds.width / 2.f,
                128.f + bounds.top - bounds.height / 2.f
            );
            window.draw(text);
```

After iterating through all students I draw the line vectors:

```cpp
        window.draw(line_graph_1.data(), line_graph_1.size(), sf::PrimitiveType::LineStrip);
        window.draw(line_graph_2.data(), line_graph_2.size(), sf::PrimitiveType::LineStrip);
        window.draw(line_graph_3.data(), line_graph_3.size(), sf::PrimitiveType::LineStrip);
```

And finally drawing the average lines:

```cpp
        std::array<sf::Vertex, 3> average_line{
            sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0.f, 100.f - average_1), sf::Color::Red),
            sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(full_width, 100.f - average_1), sf::Color::Red)
        };
        window.draw(average_line.data(), average_line.size(), sf::PrimitiveType::Lines);
        average_line = {
            sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0.f, 100.f - average_2), sf::Color::Green),
            sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(full_width, 100.f - average_2), sf::Color::Green)
        };
        window.draw(average_line.data(), average_line.size(), sf::PrimitiveType::Lines);
        average_line = {
            sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0.f, 100.f - average_3), sf::Color::Blue),
            sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(full_width, 100.f - average_3), sf::Color::Blue)
        };
        window.draw(average_line.data(), average_line.size(), sf::PrimitiveType::Lines);
```

Something similar will be a good start for a graphics library that does not having graphing built in.